# Where's this cliff in Charlevoix Québec?

Tags: identify-this, quebec

The screenshots beneath hail from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05ghkP0PeB8); the camera pans from the left to the right screenshot.

[image]

1. Where's this?
2. Is 'cliff' the correct term?
3. Can a 79 y.o. man hike this safely?

Comment: Some 79yo will have no trouble with this,  others won't get close. We have no way to know which. I suggest you edit out this part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the top of the [Montagne des Érables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montagne_des_%C3%89rables), the highest point in [Parc national des Hautes-Gorges-de-la-Rivière-Malbaie](https://www.sepaq.com/pq/hgo/index.dot?language_id=1). The shot on the right is pretty much the same as the current picture on the Wikipedia article.

> In order to reach the trails to l'Acropole ["Acropole des draveurs" is the name of the hike to the top, as I understand it], hikers must take a bus from the reception. The hike is 10 km round trip with an elevation gain of approximately 800 m (2,600 ft).